# Export .clang-format code style to Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, intellij-idea, clang-format

**Question:** Is there a way to import `.clang-format` code style in Android Studio for native development?

**Context:**

Hello all,

I am currently working on a cross-platform C++ project, which also involves Android. We have multiple subprojects, including a platform-independent common code base.

The structure of the whole repository looks something like this:

```
.
├── .idea           - Settings for CLion
├── .vscode         - Settings for VS Code
├── app
│   ├── android     - Full Android project generated by Android Studio 
│   │   └── .idea   - Settings for Android Studio
│   └── linux       - Project for targeting hardware based on Linux
├── core            - Platform-independent library with business logic etc.
└── .clang-format   - Clang-format configuration file for the whole repository
```

As you can see, we can use a single `.clang-format` file for the whole repository regardless of the used IDE (both CLion and VS Code can be configured by this file). However, I couldn't find a way to force Android Studio to also use the style defined there. I should mention that the Android project includes native C++ code, which I want to format using the same code style.

I was thinking about multiple ways to achieve this, but none of them worked. I've tried:

1. Forcing CLion to use `.clang-format` and export IDEA XML settings – does not work, as the settings simply include a directive to enable clang-format support
2. Find a way to convert `.clang-format` to `.editorconfig`, which is supported by AS – couldn't find any tools for that, and not sure if the two specs overlap enough.
3. Look for some plugins, custom *on save* actions etc. – research in progress, nothing so far.

Does anyone have a working solution or some other ideas I may try?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Studio's External Tools to call the clang-format executable directly on the file you want to format.[image: AS external tools]

It's not quite as integrated as the built-in formatter (e.g. "undo" will prompt you to reload from disk), but it gets the job done. After you create the tool, you can run it with CTRL+SHIFT+A then type "clang-format" (or w/e you chose to name it). You can also use Android Studio's Keymap to run the tool. Before creating this key-map, first close and reopen the Settings menu, otherwise the clang-format External Tool won't be there yet for you to create the shortcut.
[image: AS keymap]

Either one will format the file currently focused in the editor.

The `-style=file` argument will tell clang-format to look for your `.clang-format` file in a parent directory of the file being formatted. The `-i` flag will tell clang-format to update the file in line (instead of printing to stdout). `$FilePath$` is a substitution variable provided by External Tools and will be replaced by the file currently in focus.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look into **File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > C/C++** you will have ability to change if you want use internal android's studio clang-tidy or external one or clangd.
[image: Android Studio settings]

Comment: The question is about `clang-format`, not the tools you mentioned. AFAIK, there are no settings for the `clang-format` in Android Studio.